# How can have a line from nodes (with one or more text lines) to +(...) of the same length?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw an arrow from a node to `+(0,1.5)` such that the length of the arrow is always the same.

But it changes depending on how many rows the node has.

I don't like to use `minimum height` because if I use it the text in the one line node is vertically centered (I know I could do `{one line\\}` but it is boring because I have many nodes).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (bar) {A node with some long text};
    \node[below left = 50pt and 10pt of bar, align=center] (two) {two\\ rows};
    \draw[->] (two) -- +(0,1.5);
    \node[below left = 50pt and -80pt of bar, align=center] (twon) {two rows\\line from north};
    \draw[->] (twon.north) -- +(0,1.5);
    \node[below right = 50pt and -20pt of bar] (one) {one row};
    \draw[->] (one) -- +(0,1.5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I get same lengths by using `(two.north)` and `(one.north)`. Just the luck of the ignorant.

Comment: @jfbuj No, it doesn't work, try it!

Comment: what do you mean it does not work? see @TeXnician's answer for exactly what I tried.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nodes, when referred to by their name, use their center as the anchor. Now you don't actually want that. You want the same height of the arrow, so you need to choose an anchor that is independent of the node height. In this case, this could be one of the outer anchors like north, south etc.

The important detail for this implementation is that you position the nodes at the same height (as you do with your `below …` statements).

[image: same height]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (bar) {A node with some long text};
    \node[below left = 50pt and 10pt of bar, align=center] (two) {two\\ rows};
    \draw[->] (two.north) -- +(0,1.5);
    \node[below left = 50pt and -80pt of bar, align=center] (twon) {two rows\\line from north};
    \draw[->] (twon.north) -- +(0,1.5);
    \node[below right = 50pt and -20pt of bar] (one) {one row};
    \draw[->] (one.north) -- +(0,1.5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @CarLaTeX maybe some optical illusion or some alcohoolic beverage?

Comment: @CarLaTeX they all have the same height. Measure them in Photoshop or Illustrator.

Comment: @CarLaTeX :).......